# How to generate variable using ansible parameters like args, slurp, register and set_fact inside a doit task?

Tags: python, ansible, doit

I am creating a doit task where I need to use ansible parameters like **args, slurp, register and set_fact** inside the task  within actions to make sure the variable inside this task is accessed properly.
Do I have to define these params separately within the task before actions?

An example of how I would like to have it look like and current situation:

```
def task_xyz_load():
    actions = [
        f'set -x',
        f'git rev-parse --short master > \ {build_dir}/{xyz_project}_tables/sha_master',
        args:
            chdir: "{src_dir}"
            executable: /bin/bash,
        slurp:
            src: "{build_dir}/{xyz_project}_tables/sha_master",
        register: scm_sha_master_b64
        set_fact:
            scm_sha_master: "{scm_sha_master_b64['content'] | b64decode | trim}",
        ["echo", f"{xyz_PATH}/bin/xyz", "--url", xyz_URL,
        "load", "--name", f"{scm_sha_master}", "--force",
        f"{xyz_PROJECT}/{xyz_OUTPUT_PATH}/{xyz_PROJECT}_tables"],
    ]
    return {"actions": actions}
```

The variable I am having issue with is **scm_sha_master** which needs to be generated within the task itself using args, slurp, register and set_fact.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: I can't tell by your random mix of python and yaml syntax in your question, but are you aware that `tasks:` in ansible are a **list** of dicts, and not just one giant dict? I guess put another way: what is the _problem_ that you're experiencing? Your question is one level below "it doesn't work" because you didn't even write "it doesn't work" :-)

Comment: @mdaniel thank you for getting back to me. You are correct I have mixed yaml syntax within python in my current code. The issue I am facing is I am not sure how to currently replace those ansible tasks into Python script. I guess I have to sort those list of dicts (ansible tasks) within the script? 
In simple words I want {scm_sha_master} variable to be accessed properly in this line: "load", "--name", f"{scm_sha_master}", "--force", within this task.

Comment: The SO comments are not a good place to play "the 5 whys" -- so let me try again: what is the behavior you're getting versus the behavior you're expecting? Does it run but inaccurately? Raises an error? Reboots your computer? Do you not even have any code and that's why you didn't include any python in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved importing subprocess as below:

```
import subprocess

scm_sha_master = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD']).decode('ascii').strip()

def task_xyz():

actions = [
    ["echo", f"{xyz_PATH}/bin/xyz", "--url", xyz_URL,
    "load", "--name", f"{scm_sha_master}", "--force",
    f"{xyz_PROJECT}/{xyz_OUTPUT_PATH}/{xyz_PROJECT}_tables"],
]
return {"actions": actions}
```